# Is carrying a lance while walking guard patrols useful?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In [wheel-of-time](/questions/tagged/wheel-of-time) 'The Shadow Rising' chapter 33 'A New Weave in the Pattern' there is a Whitecloak camp.  The camp is guarded by individual Whitecloaks patrolling on foot.  The guards are carrying a lance<sup>1</sup>.

As far as I know lances are mainly used in mounted combat (see also [Lance on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance)).  Perhaps it can be used by a *group* of soldiers on foot to counter cavalry.  However these guards are patrolling alone and in the middle of the camp.

Is there any tactical reason for these guards to carry a lance?<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Whether they carry other weapons as well is left unsaid.</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>Or is their carrying a lance purely for the imago of the Whitecloaks?</sub>

Comment: They use it to poke people

Comment: Are you sure it was described as a **lance**? [Spears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear) can certainly be used in hand-to-hand combat, as we see with the Aiel.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It's definitely lances: "At intervals around the encampment white-cloaked guards marched up and down, lances shouldered like spears..."

Comment: My opinion is that this has little to do with fantasy and is more of a "scientific explanation" of the fighting technique, but in case I'm wrong, I'm answering it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of the lance on foot is [a venerable tradition](http://willscommonplacebook.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-hold-lance-in-combat-on-foot.html), presumably since, well, a lance is basically just a variant of the foot soldier's spear, albeit one that often has a small hand-guard and is weighted more toward the front to provide more punching power. As to how it might be used, it's basically the same as any long spear.

> The earlier portion of the Codex Wallerstein, probably from the first third of the 15th c., shows a halfway point about two thirds of the length of the shaft back from the tip. Talhoffer’s 1459 manuscript, now in Copenhagen, shows spears held either near the middle of the shaft or about two thirds of the way back. Paulus Kal’s fechtbuch from the third quarter of the 15th c. shows spears held near the middle of the shaft, also with the hands about an arms length apart.
>
> Olivier de la Marche gives an interesting description of a combat with lance on foot between Galiot de Baltasin and Philippe de Ternant. De Ternant took his lance with “the butt in his right palm, and the held the lance at the balance point with his left, and carried it more upright (droicte) than couched.” In contrast, his opponent held his “in the ordinary way one holds a lance for pushing” De Ternant’s stance is evidently seen as somewhat unusual, and different from the default position, which was so common that it did not need description.

Of course, lances were also often used defensively as with any long spear by the infantry, by grounding the butt and using it to defend against a charge by letting the cavalry or other charging unit run into it.

Lastly, it's possible that they were using [the original sense of the word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance#Etymology), a light throwing spear, or javelin.

Illustrations from *[Fight Earnestly](http://www.thearma.org/Fight-Earnestly.htm)*, a 15th century combat manual:

[image: Two knights preparing for battle by lances]

[image: Mid fight]

[image: Lance parried and disarmed]

[image: An attempt at a throw]

Comment: I doubt it is the original meaning, as the sentence before describes a group of cavalry which is also using lances.